# How can I return a sequelize instance asynchronously?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I can't seem to properly pass the `sequelize` object from the `service.js` file to the `index.js` sequelize variable.

Does anything look out of place?

**index.js**

```
let sequelize;
let contractModel;

(async () => {
    sequelize = await lambdaHelper.init(); //The issue is here
    contractModel = require('./models/Contract')(sequelize, Sequelize); 
})();
```

**service.js**

```
exports.init = async () => {
    let sequelize = await new Sequelize(process.env.FNI_DATABASE, process.env.FNI_USER, process.env.FNI_PASSWORD, {
        host: process.env.FNI_HOST,
        dialect: 'mysql',
        operatorsAliases: false,
        define: {
            timestamps: false,
            freezeTableName: true
        },

        pool: {
            max: 5,
            min: 0,
            acquire: 30000,
            idle: 10000
        }

    });
    return sequelize;
};
```

**service2.js**
The following code works synchronously

```
exports.init = () => new Sequelize(process.env.FNI_DATABASE, process.env.FNI_USER, process.env.FNI_PASSWORD, {
    host: process.env.FNI_HOST,
    dialect: 'mysql',
    logging: false,
    operatorsAliases: false,
    define: {
        timestamps: false,
        freezeTableName: true
    },

    pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        acquire: 30000,
        idle: 10000
    }

});
```

**results**

> *********** before *********** (node:66912) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection
>   (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'findAll' of
>   undefined (node:66912) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are
>   not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit
>   code.

**Result2**

> *********** before *********** (node:66540) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection
>   (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'findAll' of
>   undefined (node:66540) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are
>   not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit
>   code. Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'define' of undefined
>       at module.exports at

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`await new Sequelize(...)` in the code above expects that `new Sequelize` returns a promise, while this is not so. There is [`authenticate` method](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#authenticate-promise) that does that.

It should be:

```
exports.init = async () => {
    let sequelize = new Sequelize(...);
    await sequelize.authenticate();
    return sequelize;
};
```

Make sure promise rejections are always properly handled:

```
(async () => {
    sequelize = await lambdaHelper.init();
    contractModel = require('./models/Contract')(sequelize, Sequelize);
})().catch(console.error);
```

Comment: See result 2 in OP

Comment: Does it happen after you added `authenticate` and `catch`? The code that causes the problem wasn't presented in OP.

Comment: after the recommended change

Comment: *The code that causes the problem wasn't presented in OP*. Recommended changes affect only the code you've shown.

Comment: I added a Service2.js in OP that works synchronously...How do I make that act asynchronously to fulfill caller? I'm trying to make the .init() method swappable between 2 different files.

Comment: Where is Service2.js used? You can make `init`. synchronous. But you need to do `sequelize.authorize().authenticate().then(() => { ... })` any way before you use Sequelize models.

Comment: @Rod Just noticed that `authenticate` isn't supposed to return a connection, updated the answer. Not sure if it affects the problem you're having.

Comment: That's what I needed!