# How to change variable content in a then() scoop node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, synchronization, sequelize.js

i want to get database name from a table named DataBaseNames

```
 this.connexion2.query('select dbName from DataBaseNames;')
          .then((names) => { console.log(names) })
```

then i want to connect to the first database name i found

```
module.exports.connexion1 = new Sequelize(names[0], 'root', 'mdp', {

  host: '01.01.01.01', 
  dialect: 'mssql', 
  operatorsAliases: false,
  port: 1433,
  pool: {
    max: 9,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000
  },
  dialectOptions: {
    requestTimeout: 30000 // timeout = 30 seconds
  },
  logging: false
});
```

Comment: Have your tried `async`/`await`?

Comment: i don't know how to use them in the propriet way

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to keep this code synchronous. A module should export a promise of Sequelize connection, not a connection itself:

```
exports.connexion1 = connexion2.query('select dbName from DataBaseNames;')
.then((names) => {
    return new Sequelize(names[0], 'root', 'mdp', {
      host: '01.01.01.01', 
      dialect: 'mssql', 
      operatorsAliases: false,
      port: 1433,
      pool: {
        max: 9,
        min: 0,
        acquire: 30000,
        idle: 10000
      },
      dialectOptions: {
        requestTimeout: 30000 // timeout = 30 seconds
      },
      logging: false
    });
});
```

Notice that a connection is unusable until it's established, so it may be helpful to wait for `authenticate()` in this promise, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51334041/3731501).

Comment: and now in the index i got an error with this code

`code
    var sequelize = connexion.connexion1;


    fs
        .readdirSync(__dirname)
        .filter(file => {
            
            return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
        })
        .forEach(file => {
            let model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
            db[model.name] = model;
        });`

Comment: how can i use this promise in the index models

Comment: The answer states that you need to use a promise, and you're not using it. It should be: `connexion.connexion1.then(sequelize => { /* everything that depends on the connection happens here */ })`;