# Sequelize with Singleton

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, singleton, sequelize.js, serverless-framework

I'm working with `Sequelize` in `node.js` and the idea is to use the `Singleton` pattern.

Reading about how `node` works with the [modules caching](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching) and some singleton examples

My file in this moment is:

```
const DBManager = (function () {

  // Instance stores a reference to the Singleton
  let instance: any;

  let db: string = null;
  let user: string;
  let password: string;
  let host: string;
  let sequelize: Sequelize.Sequelize;

  function init(bdName: string) {
    db = bdName;
    user = process.env.MYSQL_DB_USERNAME || 'root';
    password = process.env.MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD || 'root';
    host = process.env.MYSQL_DB_HOST || 'localhost';

    return {
      open: () => {
        sequelize = new Sequelize(db, user, password, {
          host: host,
          dialect: 'mysql',
          pool: {
            max: 5,
            min: 0,
            acquire: 30000,
            idle: 10000
          },
          operatorsAliases: false,
          logging: !process.env.HIDE_LOGS
        });
      },

      testConnection: () => {
        return sequelize.authenticate();
      },

      getManagerObject: () => {
        return sequelize;
      },

      close: () => {
        sequelize.close();
      }
    };
  }

  return {
    // Get the Singleton instance if one exists
    // or create one if it doesn't
    getInstance: (bd?: string) => {

      if (!instance) {
        instance = init(bd);
      }

      return instance;
    }
  };

})();

export default DBManager;
```

**So, as expected when i require this file anywhere in my project the references are the same and works as expected.**

I'm not sure if this is the right way to implement the `Singleton pattern`, or if there is a defined and documented one, because the oficial documentation does not say anything about this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's usually no need for explicit singleton implementation. JS modules (CommonJS and ES modules in particular) are evaluated only once under normal circumstances, exported class instance is efficiently a singleton.

There's no need for IIFE as well because modules have their own scopes. Since `init` function isn't reused, there's possibly no need for it either. It can be simplified to:

```
export default {
  open: ...
  testConnection: ...
  ...
};
```

This abstraction isn't practical. There's already `sequelize` instance, creating wrapper methods for its own methods doesn't serve a good purpose.

Since a connection is usable after it's established, it makes sense to just export a promise of a connection, similarly to the one that is shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51334041/3731501).

If the configuration (database name) is available in database manager module, it's preferable to just use it in-place:

```
// db.js
const dbName = someConfig.db;
const sequelize = new Sequelize(dbName, ...);

export default sequelize.authenticate().then(() => sequelize);
```

Which is used like:

```
import dbConnection from './db';

dbConnection.then(sequelize => { /* all code that depends on the connection */ });
```

If there may be several connections, or the configuration isn't available on import, factory function is exported instead:

```
// db.js
export default dbName => {
  const sequelize = new Sequelize(dbName, ...);
  sequelize.authenticate().then(() => sequelize);
}
```

Singleton instances are naturally handled with modules:

```
// foo-db.js
import getDbConnection from './db';

export default getFooDbName().then(dbName => getDbConnection(dbName));
```

And used like:

```
import dbConnection from './foo-db';

dbConnection.then(sequelize => { /* all code that depends on the connection */ });
```

Comment: hi @estus. I made an implementation following your example and it looks good, but i have an use case with some considerations. My code will run on an aws-lambda function, so, i need to close the connection after every call to allow lambda respond successfully. the problem is, if i close the connection and call the same function again, it will be already closed so it wont be able to query the DB. Thats the reason the connection process is made on a function in my example. That way i can call it every time the function is invoked, so the connection is created every time

Comment: In your original code the only thing that persists as a 'singleton' is db name. I'm not sure if there are better recipes for AWS Lambda, but you could join both approaches shown io the answer, i.e. export factory function and use DB config in-place: `export default () => { /* get db name from config */ const sequelize = new Sequelize(dbName, ...);
  sequelize.authenticate().then(() => sequelize);
}`. You can get a connection by calling factory function. And close it by calling `sequelize.close()`.